# How to change values of one variable from data.frame using list in R (mapping feature)?

Tags: r, list, replace, mapping

I had a set-up data.frame like this

```
c1 <- c(1:5)
c2 <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
d <- data.frame(c1,c2)
d
d[,2] = as.character(d[,2])
typeof(d[,2])
mapping <- list(
  'A'='Apple',
  'B'='Blue Berry'
)
d[,2] <- as.character(mapping[d[,2]])
d
```

From my data.frame, I only want to replace 'A','B', and keep 'C','D', etc, but the result shows NULL for 'C','D',etc. I also tried different methods to give a result I want. However, I want to know why list behaves like that. Is there any way I can use list to have a result I want? Thanks.
My result should be like:

```
  c1         c2
   1      Apple
   2 Blue Berry
   3       'C'
   4       'D'
   5       'E'
```

Note: The mapping future using list is from a textbook example from my class.

Edit: Why does the result replace non-match list elements to NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mapping[d[,2]] is subsetting the mapping list by d[,2]. In other words, it's asking mapping for all of its elements that match any of the letters in d[,2]. You don't have C, D, E, as elements in mapping, so it's returning null for those values. There are many possible solutions to this; here's one:

```
ifelse(as.character(mapping[d[,2]]) == "NULL", d[,2], as.character(mapping[d[,2]]))
```